# How to unsubscribe from all deleted YouTube channels?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

Suppose you subscribed to many YouTube channels. How do you unsubscribe from all deleted or terminated Youtube channels at once without going through each one of them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a way to unsubscribe from all YouTube channels at once. Go to your [subscription manager page](https://www.youtube.com/subscription_manager) and copy this code into your browser's address bar, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
javascript:
(function(){
    var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        if (btns[i].dataset.isSubscribed == "True") {
            if (!!btns[i].dataset.showUnsubConfirmDialog) {
                delete btns[i].dataset.showUnsubConfirmDialog;
            }
            btns[i].click();
        }
    }
})();
```

I've tested it in Chrome but it should work in other browsers, too. Basically what it does is search through all the buttons on the page, find the ones that are used for unsubscribing from channels, removes the setting to ask for confirmation when you unsubscribe, then it unsubscribes from each one.

Comment: Cool, upvoting might use it someday! But the question is to unsub from channels that were terminated by youtube or deleted by its creators, if no one answers the initial question soon, I'll accept this one until things change, because it's a great answer even if it doesn't answer the original question

Comment: @Lynob Sorry, I missed that part of the question. Do you have an example of a channel that was terminated or deleted? If I can subscribe to it, I can try to see how to unsubscribe from them en masse.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJoy0SWCSewI3gP8231kxLQ - The problem is that if you're not subscribed to it already, you cannot do it now, so you have to have an existing channel subscription that's dead now

Comment: Hmm. Are you familiar with HTML/JavaScript at all? If you can inspect the unsubscribe button for that subscription (or any channel that's been terminated/deleted) and add the HTML for that button to your question, I can probably find a way to bulk remove them.

Comment: I lost it :) if I found its location in the subscription manager will let you know :) forgot its name and now cant find it, yesterday the subscription manager had a lot of dead channels, i removed them manually, now it's hard to find one and lost the one i found :)

Comment: I thought I'd check this out, "How to unsubscribe from all deleted YouTube channels?", "How do you unsubscribe from all deleted or terminated Youtube channels at once without going through each one of them?" -- but just adds javascript to delete ALL subs. Not even close.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I tried many several javascripts, but finally used the VBScript with AutoItX.

```
Option Explicit 
Dim oShell
Dim oAutoIt
Dim i

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oAutoIt = WScript.CreateObject("AutoItX3.Control")

' Wait for the FireFox window to become active - change the expected title accordingly
oAutoIt.WinWaitActive "(809) Channel list - YouTube - Mozilla Firefox", ""

' change the delay as you wish
oAutoIt.AutoItSetOption "SendKeyDelay", 50

For i = 1 To 100
    oAutoIt.Send "{TAB 3}{SPACE}{TAB}{SPACE}"
Next

WScript.Quit
```

Navigate to https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels

modify the Firefox title in the script accordingly, change the number of repetitions, save the script, go to the FF window, manually click the first "SUBSCRIBED" button, process the whole first unsubscribing and then run the script. Activate the FF window and wait... In the case of unpredictable latency modify the delay time in milliseconds.